# Pass pointer of string to lua

Tags: c, pointers, lua

I have long string in C and I want pass this to lua function. but beacause string is long I don't want pass it, I want pass pointer of string to lua. I do this by use lua_pushlightuserdata but in Lua I can't use this pointer.

C code :

```
char* st = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
lua_getglobal(myLuaState,"kk");
lua_pushlightuserdata(myLuaState,st);
lua_pcall(myLuaState, 1, 0, 0);
```

Lua code :

```
function kk(a)
    print(a)
end
```

result of code is:

```
userdata: 0x41b4d8
```

Comment: Either you load this string as Lua value (pushlstring) and use any Lua function (such as `print`) or you pass Lua a pointer (pushlightuserdata) and implement all functions you need yourself in C :-)

Comment: Try using strcpy(st, "...."); I don't think you are supposed to assign a string with a string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ffi in Luajit

```
function kk(a)
    local ffi = require("ffi")
    s = ffi.string(a)
    print(s)
end
```

the result is:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
```

Comment: FYI: `ffi` is not a part of Lua proper. LuaJIT has an `ffi` module.